# How to Introduce a delay and fadeIn on AJAX foreach return call from JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How would I go about iterating over the following foreach with a delay between each item and a fadeIn on each?

I'm not sure that .append() is the best function to use as what I'm trying to achieve is to load a templated div with the class #fan for each person in the json, which looks like:

```
[{"first_name":"adf","location":"agd","image_path":""},{"first_name":"test","location":"test","image_path":""},{"first_name":"chris","location":"london","image_path":""}]
```

Here is my code for the ajax call so far.

```
function get_fans(){

$.ajax('http://localhost/facebook_app/selectFans/', {
    type : 'get',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function (data) {
        $.each(data, function(index) {
           $('section#fans').append('<div class="fan">' + data[index].first_name + ', ' + data[index].location +'</div>');
        }); 
    },
    error: function () {
        $('section#fans').text('Could not load fans.');
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work :

```
$.each(data, function(index) {
     setTimeout(function(){
           var d = $('<div class="fan">' + data[index].first_name + ', ' + data[index].location +'</div>');
           $('section#fans').append(d);
           d.hide();
           d.fadeIn();
     }, 1000*(index +1));
});
```